# TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not None

Tags: python, python-2.7, camera, pygame, pygame-surface

i'm working with camera, with pygame, i wrote this code:

```
import pygame.camera
import pygame.image
pygame.camera.init()
list_webCam = pygame.camera.list_cameras()

webcam = pygame.camera.Camera(list_webCam[0],(640,480))
webcam.start()
img = webcam.get_image()
pygame.image.save(img, "photo.jpg")
pygame.camera.quit()
```

but it returns me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fulvio\Desktop\pygame.Camera.py", line 11, in <module>
    pygame.image.save(img, "photo.jpg")
TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not None
```

Comment: Evidently `get_image` is returning `None`. Have you tried [`query_image`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html#pygame.camera.Camera.query_image) to see if it's ready?

Answer (score 0):

Fors ome reason, you didn't get the expected image. This error means the "img" object is "None" - that is, your call to `get_image` didn't get the expected result.

As far as I can tell, you are making all the needed calls to get the camera roling, and grabbing an image - so, you'd better do some debugging in there, and check introspect what your webcam object is, and try to call the `.get_image()` method interactively, observing what it returns.

To do that, you may either paste the relevant lines directly in a Python console, or
put the `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()"  statements at the beginning, and proceed through using the [Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). (For such a short snippet, you'd probably be better pasting/typing directly in the interpreter).

If everything is fine in your setup, it may be that the camera may need some "warm-up" time between the `start` and `get_image` calls. If using the interactive mode you get your image, try adding an arbitrary delay (say 200ms), after the `start` call (use `pygame.time.delay` for that)

Also, as far as I know, pygame can't encode images to "jpg"  - you have to save then as "bmp" - or use some other library to handle the pygame.Surface object and save to other image formats.

Answer (score 0):

I just passed from python 3.5 to 2.7 and I was having the same problem you have.
After a quick search I solved it:
get_image want 1 parameter: the pygame suface!
So, you can do this:

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(0,(640,480),"RGB")
cam.start()
img = pygame.Surface((640,480))
cam.get_image(img)
pygame.image.save(img, "img.jpg")
cam.stop()
```

> img = pygame.Surface((640,480))
>
> cam.get_image(img)

I guess you don't need this anymore since it's passed more than 1 year but I hope it can help someone else.